# Batch processing of email invitations in Mattermost

Tags: bash, mattermost

I would like to invite a lot of people to a new Mattermost in one go. If I wanted to do this via the Mattermost web app, I should (in my case) click 300 times on "Invite People" and paste the mail addresses one by one into it. But in the documentation of Mattermost I discovered that I could also invite invites via the command line.

[Mattermost Docs: Command Line Tools #platform-user-invite](https://jeffschering.github.io/mmdocs/upgrade/administration/command-line-tools.html#platform-user-invite)

```
sudo ./platform user invite user@example.com myteam
```

Now I would like to know how I can use this command most intelligently to automatically run 300 mail addresses through it. Who could show me how to do this with a bash script or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where would be your source of emails? If one per line in file named `foobar.txt`, then maybe like this:

```
while read mail; do
  sudo ./platform user invite ${mail} myteam
done < foobar.txt
```

Comment: Is this a bash script?